# What is Matrix Tracing?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Given below is a words from the English dictionary arranged as a matrix

```
MATHE
ATHEM
THEMA
HEMAT
EMATI
MATIC
ATICS
```

Tracing the matrix is starting from the top left position and at each step move either RIGHT or DOWN, to reach the bottom right of the matrix. It is assured that any such tracing generates the same word. How many such tracings can be possible for a given word of length m+n-1 written as a matrix of size m * n?

Input Format
The first line of input contains an integer T. T test cases follow in each line.
Each line contains 2 space separated integers m & n indicating that the matrix written has m rows and each row has n characters.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 103
1 ≤ m,n ≤ 106
```

Output Format
Print the number of ways (S) the word can be traced as explained in the problem statement. If the number is larger than 10 rest to power 9 +7, 
print S mod (10 rest to power 9 +7)

Sample Input

```
1
2 3
```

Sample Output

```
3
```

Explanation
Let us consider a word AWAY written as the matrix

```
AWA
WAY
```

Here, the word AWAY in the matrix can be traced in 3 different ways, traversing either traversing either RIGHT or DOWN.

```
AWA
  Y

AW
 AY

A
WAY
```

Comment: I understand guys that this question might be a homework, and some people would like to close it for this, but why this question was closed because of being *unclear*? As the OP says, "Output Format: Print the number of ways (S) the word can be traced".

Comment: This is from a live programming challenge (hackerrank codesprint 5)...

Comment: @Ivan Thanks a lot :). I was just wondering why it was closed as "unclear", instead of something else..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nice question, and that's the reason I will answer it. However it seems like a homework, or a problem which was taken from a programming olympiad, which is the reason why you got so many downvotes.The answer is that we have (N-1+M-1)!/((N-1)!(M-1)!) different paths for given M and N. For example for the sample input, we have (2-1+3-1)!/((2-1)!(3-1)!) = 3!/(1*2) which is 6/2= 3.

This is because there will be M-1 moves RIGHT and N-1 moves DOWN.

Therefore for your example we can have

RIGHT DOWN RIGHT

RIGHT RIGHT DOWN

DOWN RIGHT RIGHT

So these are just the permutations of M-1 RIGHT and N-1 DOWN. 
As simple as that.

Thats the simplified (reading from file etc, were removed) algorithm

```
long getResult(int N, int M){
return Math.Factorial(N +M -2)/(Math.Factorial(N-1)*Math.Factorial(M-1));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Really thanks a lot .. i figured it out :)

Comment: How would this ever work for extremely large input (where say m,n are even in the 100+ scale)

Comment: Factorials can be estimated using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) which I guess would make things a bit more speedier. Dunno about accuracy though :)

Comment: Using Depth First Search algo you can solve it. Here is the solution.

jakharmania.blogspot.in/2014/01/matrix-tracing-algorithm-print-number.html

Comment: @c0dem4gnetic Yes, indeed, calculating factorial can be much faster, even with precomputed values up to a large number. But why you don't know about accuracy. It is right, I explained it, that it is just the permutations of the moves, and you can also try it for your self

Comment: @error.exe Nice work man! :) Yes, you can. However, I think that it is much faster with this way, because the only think that is calculated is the factorial. Apart from that, this solution is just a line of code and nothing else

Comment: @error.exe wont work for large numbers N,M

Comment: Yes, I have seen that.But the above accepted solution is just a formula but I wrote algorithm. I will find the ways to optimize it. I think its a dynamic programming problem.